# How to find all models except latest one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model `Foo` that have `date` column, and I want find all `foos` except for latest one.

```
foo = Foo.order(:date).last
foos = Foo.where.not(id: foo.id)
```

I could get the `foos` with this, is there better way to do it?

Comment: Why not combine it all, order in reverse, and offset by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest ways to achieve this result would be to query all records, then strip off the last record from the array:

```
foo = Foo.order(:date).all
foo.pop #Remove the last record from the returned array of records
```

This will work, however, you need to ensure that your query sorts/orders the returned records accordingly.

Another concise way to do this is:

```
foo = Foo.order(:date).all[0..-2]
```

Comment: should really be `foo = Foo.order(:date).all` and not `foo = Foo.all`

Comment: Of course, the order and sort matters just as I mentioned.